# Scaling size of AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have the following Problem: In a view I want to set an animationdrawable to an ImageView. It works fine when i have the layout-width and height on "wrap_content". But when I change them to fill_parent or add margin/padding attributes to my ImageView the AnimationDrawable has an other size and doesn't fit to the imageview in spite of showing the animation.

Is there a way to scale the AnimationDrawable with the ImageView or another solution for this problem? i think it might be quite simple but i can't figure out whats going wrong (Maybe some Problem with Bitmaps?).

Here is my code(quite simple):

```
    private void initAnimation(Bitmap bm) {


    statusAnim.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(bm), 300);
    zoomedImage.setBackgroundDrawable(statusAnim);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus)
        statusAnim.start();
    else
        statusAnim.stop();
}
```

And the animationdrawable xml src:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/status_blank"
    android:duration="300"/>
```

it would be great if anyone could help me solving this problem ;)

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of padding the ImageView, put the image inside a Layout and the pad the layout.